# How to match and replace strings with regex in Microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, docx

I recently got the results of a survey I had created from the LimeSurvey tool. The results were outputted in Microsoft Word .docx documents and for some reason, some strings got merged with the survey questions. For example : (SQ001)[text for a question].
I am trying to match all strings that start with (SQ001), are followed by a square bracket, then have some text, and are followed up by another square bracket. Basically, I want to extract the inner text of the square brackets while removing the rest of the characters, making:
(SQ001)[some text] --> some text

Some of the regex I tried was:

- Replace (\w{2}\d{3})[(.*?)] with \1
- Replace ((SQ[0-9]{3}))[(.*?)] with \2

But none of these worked.
(And yes, I have enabled the option 'Use wildcards')

Comment: Microsoft Word does not use standard regex. It has its own unique take. [see here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/PowerUser_MSOffice.html#:~:text=Word%20supports%20find%2Freplace%20with,in%20its%20own%20unique%20way!)

Comment: You can always copy and paste the content in Word into Notepad++ and use regex there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\(SQ001\)\[(<*>)\]`
- Select `Use wildcards` (Press More if you don't see it).
- Replace with: `\1`
- Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would try `\(SQ*\)` in the `Find` box and nothing in the `Replace` box and run it. It should delete the first part.

Then use `\[` in the `Find` box and nothing in the `Replace` box and repeat with `\]` in the `Find` box and nothing in the `Replace` box.

---

Let us know if this works by marking it answered if it works and leaving feedback where it fell short if it does not work.

Comment: Hi Brian, I thought about your solution too but it would:
1) Require 3 steps (3 replacements) instead of 1.
2) It would replace other square brackets in some other parts of the document.

This is why I needed a regex that would match the whole expression, not individual characters.
Reddy's solution worked like a charm.

Comment: @Astral Wanderer, thanks for the feedback and I appreciate the shortcomings you raised. I'm glad the other solution worked.